# How can I avoid updating the height/balance factor on the way back up my tree if no data was added?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, avl-tree

I'm recursively adding nodes to my avl tree and I'm an efficiency FIEND! Therefore, when I'm adding data called d1 and I get all the way down to a node that already has d1, I won't add it, and so I need to know how to avoid updating on the way back up the recursive "stack," as I like to think of it. If there's a way to trigger something that destroys all recursive calls that'd be splendid.

I haven't tried too much because I can't really think of a way around it.

```
private void rAdd(AVLNode<T> rootTemp, T data) {
    if (rootTemp.getData().compareTo(data) > 0) {
        if (rootTemp.getLeft() == null) {
            rootTemp.setleft(data);
            rootTemp.getLeft().setLeft(null);
            rootTemp.getLeft().setRight(null);
            rootTemp.getLeft().setHeight(0);
            rootTemp.getLeft().setBalanceFactor(0);
            return;
        } else {
            if (rootTemp.getLeft().getData().compareTo(data) == 0) {
                return;
            } else {
                rAdd(rootTemp.getLeft(), data);
                update(rootTemp);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (rootTemp.getRight() == null) {
            rootTemp.setleft(data);
            rootTemp.getLeft().setLeft(null);
            rootTemp.getLeft().setRight(null);
            rootTemp.getLeft().setHeight(0);
            rootTemp.getLeft().setBalanceFactor(0);
            return;
        } else {
            if (rootTemp.getRight().getData().compareTo(data) == 0) {
                return;
            } else {
                rAdd(rootTemp.getRight(), data);
                update(rootTemp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need this bad boy to be efficient and without any crazy imports like I see a bunch of people recommend.

Comment: Can you put the `update` after the `setBalanceFactor(0)`?

Comment: But then it would only run once, and I need to update all the possibly effected nodes.

Comment: @JTalbott Did my post helped you?